# Safe webshop with parse database

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform

I have a company where I make apps & systems.
We already made some big websites but always refused to make a webshop.
But now we really get a huge request for webshops so we want to include it in our business aswel.

If our apps or systems needed a database, we used Parse and we would love to use Parse again for the webshop.

But my question is, how can we make it safe?

Like we will have a class for example called "ORDER"
with attributes "client" , "orderitem" , ...

But we need to set open the ACL for everyone in order to add/create a new object to this class. Or am I wrong?

So my question is, how can I do this in a safe way with Parse ?

Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization

Comment: @Mozzie Someone else who can really help me out please ??